# PHP page does not load when URL is assigned to window.frame.location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some Javascript that assigns a page URL (a php page) to frame. This PHP page does not always load.

I need to understand why this happens randomly.

I use Firefox v3.5.1. Is it a browser problem, or should I handle it in any other way?

One more thing i noticed is that in my Javascript code, if i put an alert after the assignment the page always loads.

```
app.html
---------------
function updateWindow(url)
{
  window.frames.location=url
  alert("url") ; // when i put alert php page loads otherwise loading is random


}
function isloaded()
{
  if (pageloaded ==1 )
     return true;
   else
   return false ;

 }
```

### appletcode

updatedisplay(url)
{

jsobect.call(upadtewindow,url)

for ( i=0 ; 1<10 ; i++ )
  {

```
if( jsobject.call(isloaded) )
{
  return true
 }

  sleep(1000) //millisec
```

}
  return false

}

Answer (score 0):

```
window.frames.loaction=url
```

->

```
window.frames.location=url
```

"when i put alert *something* loads otherwise loading is random" points out, you need to wait till something sill be loaded. It's hard to say from your small piece of code, what is happening on the page. Hence just call your function in body.onload

Comment: it was typo i have corrected it in my post above the problem is still there

Comment: `window.frames` is usually a set of frames. You need `window.frames[0]`, but accessing any window property for frame from another domain is impossible due to security limitations.

Comment: hi i am acessing it as window.frames[0].location but my problem is,some times it loads properly and sometimes it doesnt load and i dont see any error just a blank page , but when i put a alert box after that line it always loads